# Spring Eureka: gently shutdown a service

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have service A, that is using services B1 and B2 (two instances of same service), all configured via Eureka.

Now I would like to take B1 *gently* down (so that A has not problems/delays with handling failing B1 requests). I would like to have such a procedure for that:

1. Tell B1 to stop pinging Eureka
2. Make Eureka spread the word, that B1 is going down
3. Wait until A gets the info and does not use B1 anymore
4. Then shutdown B1

I have a problem with step 1. How can I request B1 to stop pinging? Looked for some JMX operation but not found.

(If I skipped step 1, and just DELETE B1 from Eureka, it is removed from registry, but it will be quickly renewed, because B1 is still pinging Eureka)

Answer (score 3):

If you add the `cloud-starter` and `actuator` depencency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

you will have a number of managing endpoints (provided by `actuator`). A `POST` to `/pause` will result in a status of `DOWN` in eureka (thanks to `cloud-starter`). When the eureka clients receive the status, Ribbon won't route any request to your `DOWN` service. Posting to `/shutdown` will gracefully stop the application.

Comment: thanks, I have checked it (on very simple app) and it looks like it is  working (still serving the requests). One question thou, just to be sure: in logs after pausing there is an entry: "DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0". What does it mean? Does pausing influence the app behaviour anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github question](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3071), you'd better add retry because **DOWN** instance would stay for some time before being removed, otherwise there could be failed client requests which are being routed to that instance.

Answer (score -2):

add stable release version and compile "scope" in pom.xml
like

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```